# Calling a function of X in Matlab

Tags: matlab, function, bisection

(I Have seen some answers to a similar question, but they didn't really answer what was being asked so ill try to explain it a bit better than the other questions)

title is not too informative but pretty much I'm trying to write a matlab script, to complete various repetitions of the bisection method, (not really important to my question, but its a method to find the root of a mathematical function.)

The problem I'm having is that at the moment i can't figure out how to call my script for different functions. At the moment i have to write each function into the script and for each new function i have to change the script around.

I want to call my function like `bisection(f(x),a,b,N)` (don't worry about a,b,N) so that i can choose the function when i call it rather than in the script itself. But when i write my `f(x)` as something like `x^2 +x`, it tries to evaluate it for a x that does not exist and returns a error. Is there anyway to call a function of x and leave it as a function so that later i can evaluate it at different values.

```
   e.g. f(2)=6, f(a)=a^2 +a, f(b)=b^2 +b.
```

Comment: So you would like to put a function in argument of another function, that's it?

Answer (score 3):

You should use [function handles](http://fr.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/function_handle.html).

Let's take an example :

```
%Here f is the function you want to call
function M = testfun(f,x)
    M = f(x);
end
```

Then, to call it, you put as an argument a function handle

```
f = @(x) magic(x);
M = testfun(f,3)
M =

     8     1     6
     3     5     7
     4     9     2
```

Answer (score 1):

if your function `f` is an "easy" function, this seems the place to use *[anonymous functions](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/anonymous-functions.html)*

If you make sure they will always have the same inputs (f(x) always), then you can create the function as:

```
f=@(x)(x.^2+x+2);
```

or ...

```
f=@(x)(argtg(x)+log10(x.^2));
```

and then call your function passing `f` as argument. Inside `bisection` you can call `f` by `f(3)`, or any number, and it will return the result.